# How to remove the white spaces between two buttons in in Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-button

I have been trying to make my first application using Android Studio. I tried many ways including `layout_margin="-8dp"` but none of it seems to be able to remove the spaces between the buttons. I don't want the spaces in a Linear Layout to be present. Is it the natural characteristics of buttons and should I replace it with TextView and set onClick for it or is it possible to do with button also?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1fUO.jpg

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:hint="Result"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear"
                android:text="CLEAR"
                android:textColor="#06279B"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I expect no spaces between buttons. But I can clearly see the white color of the Linear Layout.

Comment: Hey, I can help you with this but the code that you've posted is incomplete. Please update is so I can tell you what to do exactly. Thanks

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AnejFSHj I have changed it to Text View but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Table Layout for this as shown below,...

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:hint="Result"
        android:gravity="right|bottom"
        android:textSize="26sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLEAR"
        android:textColor="@color/accent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/primary_light"/>

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/simpleTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/firstRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="7"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="9"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="+"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/secondRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/thirdRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="x"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/fourthRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="4">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="0"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="."
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="="
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_100dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/temp_grey"
                android:text="/"
                android:textColor="@color/accent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/margin_30dp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below, add margin in negative value for top and left/right

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:gravity="bottom">
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:hint="Result"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="+"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="-6dp">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="4"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="5"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="6"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="-"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```